# How to send GCM messages

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send same message to multiple devices in android using `GCM`. Currently I am able to send push notification on single device in java. But I want to send it to multiple devices.

so how can I do this?

my single device code is:

```
try{
Sender sender = new Sender(GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY);
Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(30)
        .delayWhileIdle(true).addData(GOOGLE_MESSAGE_KEY,
                    userMessage).build();
            result = sender.send(message, token, 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Any help or idea are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: checkout this, you can add multiple reg ids eg:
"registration_ids": ["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]


http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html

Comment: @DeepchandSingh can you post the code in java

Comment: can you check this
final List<String> androidTargets = new ArrayList<String>();// add all reg ids in this list
sender.send(message, androidTargets, 1);

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html#target

Comment: @DeepchandSingh it not working

Comment: @CommonsWare i know very well add reg ids to string array.but my question is how to use in java

Comment: If you are using Google's old server-side JAR, `send()` takes an `ArrayList<String>` where you have `token`. You were already told this. Here is a sample command-line GCM "sender" in Java that demonstrates the use of `send()` with an `ArrayList<String>`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Push/GCMCommand

Comment: sorry @DeepchandSingh .... your method is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiple device code is:

```
List<String> tokens=new ArrayList<String>();
Sender sender = new Sender(GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY);
Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(30)
.delayWhileIdle(true).addData(GOOGLE_MESSAGE_KEY,
     userMessage).build();
    sender.send(message, tokens, 1);
```